# Why is baloo such a resource hog in kde?

Tags: kde, baloo

I don't understand why baloo needs to use so much CPU for so long as opposed to updatedb which does it pretty much instantly. Can't baloo use the indexing from updatedb and get it over with? What does baloo do that locate doesn't do? Does it search inside files?

Thank you.

Comment: Baloo links: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?65271-Baloo-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updatedb only stores the filename. Baloo on the other hand indexes the filename, along with the content, mimetype and modification time of the file. Reading and indexing the content of files is what makes it consume more CPU.